# gem bullet enable/disable for some paths/controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, rails-bullet

Can I enable/disable the javascript alerts(but could be even logs) only for some paths/controllers ?

I only found how to skip models, but nothing about paths or controllers. I got a lot of alerts on activeadmin and I cannot change that code.

For example I get one for the column :user_type line: (file app/admin/admin_users.rb)

```
index do
  column :email
  column :first_name
  column :last_name
  column :user_type

  default_actions
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'alerts' ?

Comment: sorry, javascript alerts in my case (but could be even logging), but that's not important, I want to skip paths or controllers...I edited question

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by JavaScript alerts, could you do a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They updated the README to describe how to do this in 2015. For StackOverflow completeness, here's how to skip bullet in specific controller actions:

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
        around_action :skip_bullet

        def skip_bullet
            Bullet.enable = false
            yield
        ensure
            Bullet.enable = true
        end
    end
```